# How to pass total from one class to another class and display that total through toast message

Tags: android

Button add1, sub1, add2, sub2, add3, sub3, add4, sub4, order;
    TextView qtyfrenchfries, amt_frenchfries, qtychilifries, amt_chilifries,
            qtypotatofries, amt_potatofries, qtygrilled, amt_grilled, total;

```
int count1, count2, count3, count4;
double priceval1, priceval2, priceval3, priceval4;
CheckBox frenchfries, chilicheese, sweetpotato, grilledvegetables;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.starters);

    frenchfries = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    chilicheese = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    sweetpotato = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    grilledvegetables = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

    count1 = 1;
    priceval1 = 2;
    qtyfrenchfries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    amt_frenchfries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    add1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count1++;
            qtyfrenchfries.setText("" + count1);
            priceval1 = priceval1 + 2;
            amt_frenchfries.setText("$" + priceval1);

        }
    });
    sub1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sub1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count1--;
            if (count1 < 1) {
                count1 = 1;
            }
            qtyfrenchfries.setText("" + count1);
            priceval1 = priceval1 - 2;
            if (priceval1 <= 2) {
                priceval1 = 2;
            }
            amt_frenchfries.setText("$" + priceval1);

        }
    });

    count2 = 1;
    priceval2 = 3;
    qtychilifries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    amt_chilifries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    add2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    add2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count2++;
            qtychilifries.setText("" + count2);
            priceval2 = priceval2 + 3;
            amt_chilifries.setText("$" + priceval2);

        }
    });
    sub2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    sub2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count2--;
            if (count2 < 1) {
                count2 = 1;
            }
            qtychilifries.setText("" + count2);
            priceval2 = priceval2 - 3;
            if (priceval2 <= 3) {
                priceval2 = 3;
            }
            amt_chilifries.setText("$" + priceval2);

        }
    });

    count3 = 1;
    priceval3 = 2;
    qtypotatofries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    amt_potatofries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    add3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    add3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count3++;
            qtypotatofries.setText("" + count3);
            priceval3 = priceval3 + 2;
            amt_potatofries.setText("$" + priceval3);

        }
    });
    sub3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    sub3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count3--;
            if (count3 < 1) {
                count3 = 1;
            }
            qtypotatofries.setText("" + count3);
            priceval3 = priceval3 - 2;
            if (priceval3 <= 2) {
                priceval3 = 2;
            }
            amt_potatofries.setText("$" + priceval3);

        }
    });
    count4 = 1;
    priceval4 = 3;
    qtygrilled = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    amt_grilled = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    add4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    add4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count4++;
            qtygrilled.setText("" + count4);
            priceval4 = priceval4 + 3;
            amt_grilled.setText("$" + priceval4);

        }
    });
    sub4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    sub4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count4--;
            if (count4 < 1) {
                count4 = 1;
            }
            qtygrilled.setText("" + count4);
            priceval4 = priceval4 - 3;
            if (priceval4 <= 3) {
                priceval4 = 3;
            }
            amt_grilled.setText("$" + priceval4);

        }
    });

    order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

    order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double totalamount = 0;

            if (frenchfries.isChecked()) {
                totalamount += priceval1;
            }

            if (chilicheese.isChecked()) {
                totalamount += priceval2;
            }
            if (sweetpotato.isChecked()) {
                totalamount += priceval3;
            }
            if (grilledvegetables.isChecked()) {
                totalamount += priceval4;
            }
            total.setText("$" + totalamount);

        }
    });
}
```

This is my first class... I want to use the value of totalamount to another class and display it in other class...how can I do that ???

```
private ImageButton ib, ib1;
private Calendar cal;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
private EditText et;
Button book;
private int hour;
private int min;
private EditText et1;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
TextView total1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.booktable1);
    /*
     * total1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); long
     * textView10=getIntent().getLongExtra("total2", 0); String
     * str="Total : "+textView10; total1.setText(str);
     */
    // mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_button);
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    book = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bookbtn);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    /*
     * total1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     * total1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("total2"));
     */
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show the DatePickerDialog
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show the DatePickerDialog
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (et1.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || et.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Booktable.this)

                        .setTitle("Field is Empty")

                        .setMessage("Either Date or Time is missing")

                        .setNeutralButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,

                                            int which) {

                                    }

                                }).show();

            } else {

                /*
                 * Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                 * Uri.fromParts( "mailto","rupesh.mishra89@gmail.com",
                 * null)); intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
                 * intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
                 * startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                 * "Choose an Email client :"));
                 */

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table is booked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            ;

        }
    });
}

@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, min,
                false);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        if ((selectedYear < year)
                || ((selectedMonth < month) && (selectedYear == year))
                || ((selectedDay < day) && (selectedYear == year) && (selectedMonth == month))) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Booktable.this)

            .setTitle("Wrong Input!")

            .setMessage("Please Enter Valid Date")

            .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,

                int which) {

                }

            }).show();
        } else {
            et.setText(selectedDay + " / " + (selectedMonth + 1) + " / "
                    + selectedYear);
        }
    }
};
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        int hour;
        String am_pm;

        if (hourOfDay > 12) {
            hour = hourOfDay - 12;
            am_pm = "PM";
        } else {
            hour = hourOfDay;
            am_pm = "AM";
        }

        et1.setText(hour + " : " + minute + " " + am_pm);

        if (hourOfDay < 10) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Booktable.this)

            .setTitle("Hotel not open")

            .setMessage("Hotel Timings: 10 AM to 12 PM")

            .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,

                int which) {

                }

            }).show();
            et1.setText("");
        } else {
            et1.setText(hour + " : " + minute + " " + am_pm);
        }

    }
};
```

I want to show total through toast message......

Comment: it would be nice if you would shorten the code to make your problem more clear. You can use intent extras to pass data from one activity to another.

Answer (score 1):

In your first Activity, create an Intent, put a bundle with the data in it, and start the second Activity with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putDouble("total", total);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in `onCreate` of your second Activity you can get the data from the bundle and display the Toast.

```
double totat = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("total");
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "some text " + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a getter method in the first class, something like

```
public double getTotalAmount()
{
    return totalamount;
}
```

Then in the second class, you'll need to create a reference to the first class, and then where you want the Toast, you can have

```
Toast.makeText(this, *first class*.getTotalAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: The other answers are a much better option, didn't even think of that.

Comment: this is working,but not properly, everytime i click on order, it is increasing the amount, means returning the total amount, how to fix it..

Comment: I don't get what you mean. If the total amount changes, you'll need to call getTotalAmount() again. It's not going to magically change or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use intent.putextra. Something like this should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);   
intent.putExtra("total", total);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your activity2 try to get the total you put before.

```
int total = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("total");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are activity classes.

So, the best way to pass values from one activity to another one is using Intent.
You can do somethink like this:

In the send class you put the value in Intend and start the second activity:

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Your2Activity.class);
i1.putExtra("YourKey", YourValue);
startActivity(i1);
```

In the second Activity you can retrieve your value:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String result = intent.getStringExtra("YourKey");
```

To show the result is simply:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Total: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```